# Cakephp: pagination with find type "threaded"

Tags: cakephp

I want want to paginate the find query result which type is "threaded".

Like

```
$this->Model->find('threaded');
```

Do anyone have idea , how could it possible???

Answer (score 0):

You can't. `find('threaded')` won't work well with conditions, and less so with `LIMIT` statements, which are used by the PaginatorComponent.

You will have to do the pagination with a normal find, and may augment the resulting data with additional queries, depending on what exactly you need to display.